# VS 2015 SSIS project is continuously breaking

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis

While working on VS 2015 editor on one SSIS project the editor gets closed repeatedly. I have a package which has more than 30 tasks in it. When I open that and make changes and try to save that, it gives out of memory exception and not allow to save. Also sometimes it gets closed abruptly while working. Can someone help me in this.

Comment: Have you tried removing the **.vs**  folder from your source directory and reloading the solution again?

Comment: No will try that. Thanks!!

Comment: Is your computer legitimately running out of memory to run VS? I'd check the task manager while running it just to rule that out.

Comment: No it is not taking that much memory while running. It is completely weird issue.

Comment: You could try setting "DelayValidation" to true.